# SegFault when setting up 2D character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, calloc

I am trying to set up a 10x10 grid filled with '$' characters and then print it.

```
    char **plot;
    plot = (char**)calloc(100, sizeof(char));

    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i< 10; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<10; j++){
                    plot[i][j] = '$';
            }
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
                    printf("%c", plot[i][j]);
            }
    }

    free(plot);
```

This is my code so far, when I run this I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: This is a 2d array of 100 chars. Have you allocated memory for each row? Also, is your type of `plot` `char` or is it `char *`?

Comment: @ggorlen not sure what you mean. is it not possible to allocate a 2D array with one calloc?

Comment: You need a `malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10)` for the row pointers, then 10 `char`s for each row. That should be 11 `malloc`s total. This code only asks for 10 bytes of memory (`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1).

Comment: One line: `char (*plot)[10] = malloc(10 * sizeof *plot);`, then lose the ensuing calloc entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only allocated a list of pointers (and incorrectly)! The line:

```c
plot = calloc(10, sizeof(char*)); // Note the extra * in sizeof(char*)
```

Creates a 1-dimensional array (list) of 10 pointers.  What you then need to do is allocate each of these pointers a buffer of 10 characters:

```c
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    plot[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // Here use "sizeof(char)" but it's always "1"
```

And, don't forget to call `free` for each of the calls to `calloc` and `malloc` when you're done with the buffers!

*Also, you needn't call `calloc` - you could just use `malloc(10 * sizeof(char*))`: there's really no point setting all the pointers to zero when you're immediately going to replace them all with what the 'other' `malloc` calls will return.*

Comment: @ggorlen I left the original `calloc` because that what the OP used; in the `malloc` call in my code, I included the `* sizeof(char)` to highlight the difference between this and the `sizeof(char*)` in the first call. But you're right, of course!

Comment: @WhozCraig OP doesn't want 10 ***strings*** but a grid of 10 x 10 ***characters***.

Comment: =P too much scotch last night (honestly, there is such a thing =P)

Comment: Alternately, keep the `calloc` of 100 items, but cast it to `char(*)[10]`, using `char(*plot)[10] = calloc(100, sizeof(char));`. Then the `plot[i][j]` work as intended and access items in the 2D array.